# Color picker in touch devices

Tags: gui-design, intuition, dialog

I'd like to know about design templates for color pickers that would work well on touch devices, more precisely on tablets. It should be intuitive, it's for non-experienced people and specially for **children**.

I've made some research and also found some good answers here and here, but I'm not happy with any simply because those based on circles aren't simple enough - and they are not very precise since I'll be using a finger to choose not a mouse pointer -, and those with pre-set values just don't offer a big range of colors.

So, to summarise I can list these requirements:

- simplicity, as it will be used by non-professionals;
- touch devices only;
- screen size: tablets;
- great range of colors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is going to to be used by non-professionals, I would suggest using **swatches** in the first place. It's a great starting point, often offering proper balance between choice and usability for such use.

**As a second level** (only for situations, where swatches are not enough for user) you can indeed provide an optional color picker. You have following options here:

- **linear** (sequential) - where each color is followed by another (you basically control the hue value and need to add another controller for saturation and lightness). *This one is the mose intuitive one within the slider-controlled ones, in my opinion.*
- **multi-factor** - with sliders used to control separately different color factors, e.g. red, green and blue (or CMYK, or even more complex LAB). *Main problem: difficult to understand for newbies.*
- **two-dimensional** - which has the advantage over the previously mentioned ones, as on one space you can control two factors (hue and saturation or black point), but you still need another control to add the third one (example, not for touch devices but still communicating idea: http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/raphaelcolorpicker-simple-color-picker/). *Main problem: fine tuning (touch resolution).*

**There is also “the middle path”**, where you can offer users something between swatches and color picker, like here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp

For touch devices, I would suggest live **preview of the selected color somewhere above/beside the finger**, so that it is not covered by the fingertip.

Below you can find a color picker in Adobe Ideas, where you have some of these implemented: at first, user is shown only the  swatches, then, after clicking the **>** chevron, s/he can access the sliders, RGB or HSL ones (disregard this themes stuff, it is used for further customization) - and the color is shown in the "color" area on the left, so user does not cover it with hand.

[image]